# Failed Offline Update" - how to find which package failed

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, kubuntu

I have a Kubuntu 22.04.2 LTS machine using Ubuntu Pro which hung on an update a couple of weeks ago. The machine got shutdown and since then I am presented with a dialog box when I log in that says:

Failed Offline update
Failed to update 1 package
The transaction did not complete

and it gives me two buttons to push - "Open Discover" and "Repair System". The Repair System button does not appear to do anything. The Open Discover button does in fact open Discover but Discover doesn't present me with any obvious info but maybe I'm not looking in the right place? I normally do updates from the command line.

I tried using journalctl -p 3 but it only goes back to the 1st of the month and I think this probably happened late last month. I've used zgrep on the apt/history.log files (compressed and uncompressed) with no luck.

I've tried 'apt list' and 'dpkg --list' and grepping for failed, offline and other key words but nothing pops up.

How can I determine what file failed?

Comment: Have you tried `sudo apt -f install` to see if any clues are available; however as `discover` also updates snap packages (& more depending on how you've configured your system) the `apt` won't be checking everything that discover reports (eg. `discover` can be used for flatpak & more meaning more commands/package type checks need to be performed)..

Comment: Thanks. sudo apt -f install reports nothing other than 3 packages held back. 

I found a couple of posts talking about 'debsums -ca' which reports a few things but doesn't identify any single package. (The results don't post well so I deleted them but can supply.)

Comment: I didn't realize this would be a problem but I filed a bug report with KDE and they say the version of Plasma shipping with 22.04.02 LTS is no longer eligible for support so either I upgrade out of LTS or wait until (hopefully) Kubuntu advances within LTS.

Comment: For reporting bugs upstream, you need to be using a recent release of Kubuntu (for KDE), ie. 23.04, 22.04 is three releases ago thus of course has an older (but LTS) version of KDE Plasma, along with older libs/toolkits (Qt5). Kubuntu do provide newer versions via *backports*  (https://launchpad.net/~kubuntu-ppa/+archive/ubuntu/backports) but Ubuntu is a *stable release* system & only fixes are backported to repositories, as Qt5 is also used by Lubuntu (LXQt) & Ubuntu Studio (KDE Plasma) as well as many apps.. not just Kubuntu.  If you file on launchpad, someone may re-test on a newer release